# A question on aesthetics: How should a diagram presenting latencies of network IP packets look like?

Tags: pgfplots, diagrams

So I am pretty much gathering the results of my work for my thesis (which is around measuring network bandwith and packet latency) and I am not really pleased with how my diagrams look or more like how they compare to each other.

In one case, I might present the packet latency where there is only minor load on the system. Because of that, packet latency is usually much lower than in scenarios with high load.

Obviously, the scaling is going to be much different. But if I start to scale each diagram individually to fit the data, comparing the diagrams is also going to be more difficult.

So this is my diagram at small load:

[image]

at medium load:

[image]

and at substantial load:

[image]

As you can see you can barely see anything. The red and green lines are the median and mean values. I am also not sure how to draw those.

I thought about scaling the proportion (y-axis) to 25% but then I also have scenarios where 75% of packets had the same latency number.

Btw. the crosses are for very small proportions (0.05% and lower) where a ybar doesn't make sense.

Any ideas how I could solve this?

Edit: I made a new approach which is quite a bit better (I think):

[image]

I made the vertical lines for mean and median latency stand out more and the percent values are now accumulated over the x-Axis.

One positive point about that:

- no more ugly crosses on the x-Axis

negative:

- it is hard so see the "outliers" (because there may be some very small amount of packets which had a latency of 1500µs)
- possible fix: Add 99%-percentile line

Any opinions on that new approach?

Example data (for the first way of plotting the data): https://pastebin.com/wpmShWN2

Note: For median and mean values there are two entries: The one with "95%" is for my pgfplot program to know how high to draw the vertical line. The real measured value is in the other entry.

Answer (score 1):

I once was in the same situation of yours.
Unless there are external reasons forcing you to have the *y* axis spanning from 0% to 100% (let's say, your advisor ;) ) your intentions of having informative plots are good (and right).
To be informative it's the primary objective of well conceived plots.

I suggest you to have a look at Edward Tufte's approach on how to present data with plots.
Tufte's plots are not that common, but are quite informative.
Here are some notes on their implementation https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb34-2/tb107dugge.pdf

Otherwise, default settings of `pgfplots` should already provide a good output.

Another idea is to normalize the data with respect to the maximum y value of the current plotted data, so that you'll have all the *y* axes of the plots from 0 to 1, without losing information on the behavior of the data.

Do you mind sharing some data file so that we can give it a try?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I edited my original posting with a new approach and example data